# error denegado cuando se ejecuta el comando para crear un nuevo proyecto en laravel? - mkdir(): Permission denied

Tags: laravel, linux, linux-mint

hola gente les comento mientras ejecuto el comando de composer:

**composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel system**

que es el que viene en la documentacion oficial de laravel :
[doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/installation)

```html
/project/laravel$  composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel system
Installing laravel/laravel (v6.12.0)

In ProjectInstaller.php line 68:
                              
  mkdir(): Permission denied  
                              

create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--repository REPOSITORY] [--repository-url REPOSITORY-URL] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-secure-http] [--keep-vcs] [--remove-vcs] [--no-install] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<package>] [<directory>] [<version>]
```

basicamente que no tengo permiso para ejecutar la accion de mkdir? supongo que no me permite crear la carpeta system donde se estaria guardando mi proyecto como lo comenta el comando que estoy ejecutando, intente ejecutar el comando com root (estoy usando linux) composer me indica que no lo puedo ejecutar como root:

> root@karol:/project/laravel# composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel system
> Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details

Alguien tiene alguna recomendacion de como crear un proyecto en linux usando composer? anteriormente lo habia ejecutado en ubuntu y no tenia problema en este momento estoy usando linux mint no creo que sea eso el problema.

Comment: has probado con el comando **sudo** `sudo composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel system`

Comment: Parece un problema de permisos sobre /project/laravel, ya revisaste cual es el usuario propietario de la carpeta laravel y cuales son sus permisos ?

Comment: Y tu usuario permisos para crear un directorio ahí? Probaste `mkdir test` por ejemplo?

Comment: @Juanmhs es lo primer oque pense pero  cuando lo ejecuto asi me pide password entoces : /project/laravel$  sudo sudo composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel system
[sudo] password for karol:  
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ ese es el problema composer no me permite crear folder como lo comento en mi pregunta , si uso root composer me dice que no y si no lo uso me sale ese error.

Comment: " laravel new blog" por ejemplo que se encuentra en su  documentacion en ingles me indica la terminal que el comando no exsite , te muestro los comandos que ejecute  como root: root@karol:/project/laravel# l
system/
root@karol:/project/laravel# mkdir app
root@karol:/project/laravel# l
app/  system/
root@karol:/project/laravel# cd app
root@karol:/project/laravel/app# l
root@karol:/project/laravel/app# laravel new appPHP
laravel: command not found
root@karol:/project/laravel/app#

Comment: existe alguna maera de crear el proyecto sin composer?

Answer (score 0):

Cambia los permisos del folder donde quieres instalar  con 775 o 777 , el 777 es un tanto peligroso por que da permiso de escribir a cualquiera, pero si es meramente un localhost no hay problema

Desde terminal ejecuta

**chmod 775 /project/laravel**

Opcionalmente puedes cambiar también el usuario al que pertenece

**chwon usuario:usuario /project/laravel**

Comment: obtengo este error al aplicar esos permisos :  composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel Appsystem
Cannot create cache directory /home/karol/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
Cannot create cache directory /home/karol/.composer/cache/files/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
Cannot create cache directory /home/karol/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache